# failed to invoke chaincode deed, error: transaction returned with failure: ReferenceError: bor is not defined

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I'm using node js sdk to build chaincode. I'm having two chainocodes named deed.js and bor.js that are installed on the same channel. I want to send data from deed.js to bor.js. So I used the method InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName, args, channel) to send data from deed.js to bor.js. My implementation for invoke chaincode method is as follows.

const args=[deedid,newowner,newownerid,landaddress];
  const response = await ctx.stub.InvokeChaincode(bor, args, mychannel);

Where bor is the name of the chaincode to which I want send data in form of arguments args. mychannel is the channel name where both deed and bor chaincodes are installed. When I try to run the smart contract it is throwing an error as mentioned in the title. Is my syntax correct?Am I giving the correct format for the chaincode name parameter of invokeChaincode function?

Comment: Can you share the command of peer chaincode installation which you used.What is the name you used there ?

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It's an syntax error and I have resolved my error. The correct syntax is  const response = await ctx.stub.invokeChaincode('deed', ['queryDeed', deedNumber ], 'mychannel'); . I don't know how to close this question. So i left as it is! Anyways Thanks for your time!